# Applying a discount to a stripe subscription in Clickfunnel

Tags: javascript, discount, coupon

We have a one-click upsell page on clickfunnel that is linked to a stripe subscription plan.

https://dyslexiadaily.clickfunnels.com/ttmt-upsell-order

It's currently priced at $49 but we want to apply a $42 coupon for the first month so it should only charge $7.

We found this from stripe support but have no idea how to use it on clickfunnel.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#coupons

Is there a javascript code I can use to make it recognize the coupon code before sending the purchase order to stripe?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a javascript for using the Stripe coupon from your clickfunnel (gosh I wish there was).

The way I have solved this in the past was to create two products in both CF and Stripe. Then use javascript to change the selected product on the checkout page based on the coupon code being entered correctly. Then you have to have some process to switch the customer from one discounted subscription plan to the regular price so that they wil be charged the correct amount the following month (be sure proration is disabled so the customer does not get charged the difference for the remainder of the month).